# Fractional number to time in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel's `Time` function doesn't seem to honor fractional part of seconds. Here I have 3 columns for hour, minute and second part of the time in columns A, B and C. In column E, I'm converting these values into time using the `Time` formula.

[image]

I have set `h:mm:ss.000` formatting on column E to see what it's actually making from my input. It looks like `Time` function is only taking the integer part from column C value. What should I do to make it care for the fractional part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `TIME` function. Do the adjustments yourself - for example:

```
=A2/24+B2/1440+C2/86400
```

Comment: Thanks. Probably I was overengineering this simple problem.